# LUKS Disk Encryption on Raspberry Pi 3b and Ubuntu Desktop 20.04, no memory for the keyslot

Tags: encryption, raspberrypi, luks

I would like to encrypt my Ubuntu installation on the RPi 3, and have followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1296450/1159414) answer. But when I try the manually decrypt from initramfs I get the error: `not enough available memory to open a keyslot`

If anybody know hows to fix/work around this I would be very grateful.

Comment: If you’ve set your Pi to use LUKS2, then the Pi 3b doesn’t have enough physical memory to decrypt partitions beyond a certain size. LUKS1, however, is usable on a Pi 3b.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it now works flawlessly

Comment: @Matigo Could you please make your comment into an answer below?